# How do I get rid of the "Invalid syntax near File. Expecting '.', ID, or QUOTED_ID"?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, schema

I'm trying to change over schema in a third party db. It's old. And everything has moved over except two lines.

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER db_owner.File

ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER db_owner.User
```

Now I see that File and User are SQL keywords. And that's why I'm getting that error. Is there a way to tell SQL to ignore them as keywords? So it can run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enclose the keywords in square brackets.

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER db_owner.[File]

ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER db_owner.[User]
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand: As I said in my OP, it's a third-party DB. i.e. I didn't create or name the tables.

Comment: Right, but you can give that feedback to the 3rd party. Who knows, if you have a decent vendor, they might be willing to phase out the messes they create.

Comment: Well it's a well-known .NET open source wiki software. But I will drop them an email. Good point.